# How do I vary the playback speed in VLC using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: vlc

How do I vary the playback speed of media in VLC Media Player using keyboard shortcuts?

I used to be able to do this by holding down Cmd-Alt-[Forward Arrow or Back Arrow] but this doesn't seem to be working any more. Instead it's jumping the video forward and backwards by 19 seconds when I use this key combination.

Is there a way to restore the variable speed shortcut behaviour?

Answer (score 46):

VLC has a wonderful short cuts menu where you can see or even set the shortcuts.

Open the VLC preferences and the Hotkeys tab.

Restart VLC after making the hotkey change.

The following was tested by me on VLC Version 2.0.9 Twoflower (Intel 64bit).

[image: VLC shortcuts]

<sub>Ranting:
I wish every app would have such easy access and feature, rather them me searching the Google to find out what Hotkeys they use and how to set them.
End of Rant.</sub>

Comment: Yes, make sure to restart VLC after the hotkey changes, otherwise they probably won't work!

Comment: Also, VLC allows to customize the interface, e.g. placing a slow down button next to stop. :)

Answer (score 20):

To increase/decrease playback speed on VLC/Mac use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: On Linux at least, `+` doesn't increase speed beyond 1x. `]` does.

Answer (score 11):

use '[' and  ']' keyboard input for decreasing and increasing the speed respectively.

Comment: Are you attempting to clarify that caps lock is not required to use these keys, against a previous revision of this answer?

Comment: ']' for faster (fine)

'[' for slower (fine)

Thanks Gyan

Comment: This answer is apparently wrong for current downloads. These are the keys I always used for VLC on my Windows box, and when it failed I found this page searching for how to determine what the shotcut keys were.  Turns out for a newly downloaded copy of VLC for OS X, there is no default key bindings for "faster (fine)" or "slower (fine)".

Comment: As @Michael said these are "Not Set" by default, but you can easily change them to this, but you have to restart VLC for them to take effect.

Comment: These work by default on VLC 3.0.9.2 on Linux.